# Count different dependent coincidences in multiple lists

Tags: excel-formula

I have a table with 2 colums filled with numbers, like this:

```
A | B
-----
1 | 2
3 | 1
4 | 3
5 | 2
1 | 2
```

I would like to know how to obtain the number of coincidences in which there is a '1' in B A and out of those how many have a '2' in their correspondent row in B.
So for the example the result would be 2, because there is a 1&2 in the first row and a 1&2 in the last row:

The equivalent in code would be something like:

```
%MATLAB SINTAX
A = {1 ; 3 ; 4 ; 5 ; 1};
B = {2 ; 1 ; 3 ; 2 ; 2};
sum = 0;

for i=1:length(A)
    if(A(i)==1 and B(i)==2)
        sum = sum+1;
    end
end
```

In this case, sum is the result that i want.

I was hoping to do something like SUM(IF(AND(A1:A5=1,B1:B5=2),1,{0))

Notes: This is for an assignment, the rules are simply no macros, just one formula without partial results in other cells.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You need to look up the definitions for *row* and *column* then use them appropriately. When done, try `=countifs(a:a, 1, b:b, 2)`

Comment: Tried that, didn't work

Countifs(a1:a5, 1 , b1:b5, 2)

Also

Countifs(a1:a5=1 , b1:b5=2)

Didn't work either

Comment: *'Didn't work'* is neither a valid error coded nor valid error description.

Comment: @LuisitoB =COUNTIFS(A1:A5,1,B1:B5,2) works for me it gives 2

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways and as the comments state, `COUNTIFS()` would be the simplest and most effective...

As you provided a coded example I thought I would try to formulate your logic as closely as I can with an array formula like this: (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> while still  in the formula bar)

`=IFERROR(SUM(IF(IF(A1:A5=1,B1:B5)=2,1)),0)`

We build an array of either FALSE or the resulting `B:B` cell content using the inner if (`IF(A1:A5=1,B1:B5)`) then equate that array against the logical in the outer `IF([innerIf]=2,1)` to get an array of FALSE or 1 which we then sum to get the result. I think it will handle the errors as is treating FALSE as 0, but as I wrote this pseudo I wrapped it in an `IFERROR()` just in case (if errors still occur, provide the false variable of the `IF()` statements as 0).

The issue with `AND()` is that it doesn't perform in array constructs, or at least I have never got it to produce an array result.